# What action I can take on closed questions? How those going to penalize me and what steps that I can take to pay back that penalty?

Tags: discussion

I have learned that questions can be closed for various good reasons. How ever if my question get closed and if there is no way to improve in order to reopen,
   (1) What are the appropriate actions that I can take on those closed questions?
   (2) How those closed questions going to penalize me? What are the negative effects having closed questions in my questions list?
   (3) How can I pay that penalty and escape from the negative effects?

Answer (score 7):

1. You don't need to do anything. The problem is that closing a question looks like punishment, but it is really not intended to be as aggressive as it looks: all it means is that five people on this website don't think it is a good fit for the site. So don't worry about having a few closed questions. If you really think your question wouldn't be useful for any future visitors, you can delete it. But consider duplicate questions: they are useful in that they can lead future visitors to the original question.
2. There is no penalty. Hurray! The only exception to this is that if you really have tons of questions that are not only closed, but also of very low quality, and you don't seem to learn from suggestions for improvement, you may get suspended after a long time. But this is only for extreme cases; I wouldn't worry about it. You would probably hate this site long before that happened and move on to a regular English learning forum.
3. There is no real penalty, but you can simply ask more non-closable questions to improve people's opinion of you, if that's what you're afraid of. I haven't looked at your questions; sometimes people can be mean, so don't take it all too personally.

Answer (score 3):

> What are the appropriate actions that I can take on those closed questions?

You can improve your question to make it acceptable. If it was closed as duplicate, you can edit it to make it not a duplicate, if that is possible; if it was closed a not a real question (which generally means the question was too vague), make it more focused, and describe exactly what you want to know.
After you did that, you can flag your question for moderation attention, explaining that you think the question is a good suit for the site.

This doesn't warrant your questions are re-opened, but gives you a chance. If that fails, look at the questions asked from other users, and learn from them.

> How those closed questions going to penalize me? What are the negative effects having closed questions in my questions list?

If you were on *Stack Overflow*, having closed questions, with a low score, and some of them were deleted, that would cause you to be banned from asking further questions. As long as I know, this has not been yet implemented in other sites (apart *Stack Overflow*, *Super User*, and *Programmers*.
Still, if you would keep asking the same question, which is then closed as duplicate, and you keep doing that for some questions, it is probable you would be temporary suspended.

> How can I pay that penalty and escape from the negative effects?

Just learn how to ask questions. If you keep asking too vague questions, without showing any effort in writing better questions, it is probable they will be always closed.
If you are not sure the question is acceptable, you can always ask here on meta (when your reputation is higher than 5).
I take you are saying *penalty* to refer to your closed, or down-voted questions. Apart from that, and your questions being deleted, there is not any penalty, if we exclude your account being temporary suspended.